# How would you say 'overthink' in Russian?

Tags: перевод

> Don't overthink it, it's about you getting work done.

I have yet to find a translator software that correctly translates expressions like "overthink" in a way that's actually used in the target language. At least that's the case with Portuguese and Spanish (both of which I'm fluent in).

Comment: Maybe "не усложняй"? What's the context, though? Is it about over-engineering a technical system? Is it about thinking to much about whether I am doing it right or not? Something else?

Comment: Will you accept Matt's answer?

Answer (score 12):

In this case I'd translate the whole sentence in a different way, rather than choose word for "overthink". For example,

> *Меньше думай, больше делай* --> Think less, do more
>   *Глаза боятся, а руки делают* --> The eyes fear but the hands work

Considering "to overthink", I doubt if there is a good bookish word but commonly people say "*зацикливаться*", i.e. "*don't overthink it*" --> "*не зацикливайся на этом*".

There is also a couple of "slanguish / teenager" variants: "*не загоняйся*" or "*не парься*" (the latter stands for both "don't think / don't worry").

UPD. OK, for this case "*мудрить*" seems to fit nice:

> *Ты не мудри, просто сделай свою работу*

Comment: http://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/Don%27t+overthink+it.

Answer (score 1):

Just my five cents, a bit closer to the original phrase:

> Не думай больше, чем надо. Суть в том, чтобы ты **сделал** работу.

with an emphasis on a word "сделал" (Do not think more than necessary. The point is that you get the work done).

Even closer, a bit clumsy, but acceptable (I could say so, but primitive minds could get stuck in an attempt to extract the matter from the sentence):

> Не думай больше, чем надо. Вся суть в **выполнении** работы тобою.

(Do not think more than necessary. The point is in accomplishing of the work by you)

I find the last Matt's variant (не мудри) is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `чересчур замороченный` is exactly `too overthinked`- it's just that unlike `overthinked`, `замороченный` is acceptable only in colloquial speech.

So, in some cases it's acceptable to use `заморачиваться` or `загоняться` (more slang), so one can say something like:

> Не заморачивайся слишком уж, тут главное чтобы работа была сделана.

or

> Не загоняйся, главное - сделать работу.